# Does Google require you to have a certificate/license for using encryption in an Android app?

Tags: encryption, android

Does Google require you to have some sort of certificate or license in order to use encryption technologies in an Android app?

Answer (score 0):

They use Bouncy Castle internally, which is unrestricted. As I've never heard of such a certificate/license in the dev-crypto mailinglist of BC, you can safely assume the answer is no. The standard IANAL (I am not a lawyer) applies. Note that some algorithms may have patenting issues though (IDEA for instance).